# Inserting Into A Database With PDO Commands

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am learning PDO commands and have been following the examples

My query below works fine for the SELECT command but not for the INSERT command. I cannot see what is wrong with the INSERT command. The error I am getting is 'Uncaught Exception (PDOException) with message SQLSTATE[42000]: syntax error or access violation : 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax'

```
$descr='1M18';
Require('connect_db.php');  

//SELECT COMMAND         
$stmt=$mysql_link->prepare("SELECT descr,area_id FROM berthmove WHERE descr=:descr");
$stmt->execute(array(':descr'=>$descr));
foreach($stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) as $row) {
 echo $row['descr'];    
 echo $row['area_id'];
}

//INSERT COMMAND
$msg_type_berth='Hello';
$railinfo2=$mysql_link->prepare("INSERT INTO berthmove ('msg_type_berth') VALUES(:msg_type_berth)");
$railinfo2->execute(array(':msg_type_berth'=>$msg_type_berth));         
$mysql_link=null;
```

Comment: look at your post. Look at the masses of whitespace in your code. Don't just copy-paste from your editor, always preview your post to make sure it looks right before hitting submit. (especially note that the code block is based on 4 spaces. Don't add more leading space or you're just creating a huge block of unnecessary scrolling)

Comment: Did you try to connect to MySQL with the CLI tool (`> mysql -u... -p... -h... yourdbname`), and tried copy-pasting your query there to see what it says?

Comment: When I try pasting the problem line in it says ERROR 1064 (42000) : You have an error in your SQL syntax

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably the error is generated by the single quotes around the column name, try to use:

```
$railinfo2 = $mysql_link->prepare('INSERT INTO berthmove (msg_type_berth) VALUES(:msg_type_berth)');
```

Comment: don't edit your question to make it no longer have broken code: other people finding this question with a similar problem don't benefit from that. Leave the question as having the broken code, mark the answer as correct, and everyone wins.

Comment: @user2635961, Nevermind! You should leave the version with error in you question, this way other users can view the problem too.